# How to use Cloudflare's R2 bucket with next JS 13 api?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I've recently came across Cloudflare's R2 bucket. this bucket has generous free tier which i wanted to use for my personal projects. but there are no docs on how to use it with next JS 13. there might be some tutorials showing how to use it with Node js.

so can how can i upload to R2 storage using Next 13 API route?

Answer (score 6):

copying this solution from [my reddit comment.](https://old.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/146jkiy/how_to_use_cloudflare_r2_for_uploading/jnvwgat/) i went with [Option 2: Upload to AWS S3 directly from Browser](https://www.zachgollwitzer.com/posts/file-upload-strategies-s3-nodejs-express-react-uppy#option-2-upload-to-aws-s3-directly-from-browser)

can't believe nobody wrote a guide on using cloudflare r2 with next 13's `app/` directory so i just did ↓

#### cloudflare cors policy

```
[
    {
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:3000"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "HEAD",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

#### install these dependencies

npm install @aws-sdk/client-s3 @aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner

#### .env.local

> generate tokens from cloudflare r2 dashboard. watch the official youtube video on cloudflare workers youtube channel

```
R2_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx
R2_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxx
R2_BUCKET_NAME=xxxx
R2_ACCOUNT_ID=xxxx
```

#### lib/r2.ts

```
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'

export const r2 = new S3Client({
    region: 'auto',
    endpoint: `https://${process.env.R2_ACCOUNT_ID}.r2.cloudflarestorage.com`,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.R2_ACCESS_KEY_ID || '',
        secretAccessKey: process.env.R2_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || '',
    },
})
```

#### app/(site)/admin/page.tsx

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import { DocumentIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/solid'

const Admin = () => {
    const [file, setFile] = React.useState<File>()

    const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.target.files) {
            const currentFile = event.target.files[0]
            setFile(currentFile)
        }
    }

    const handleUpload = async () => {
        if (!file) return

        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', file)

        const response = await fetch('/api/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
        })
        const { url } = await response.json()
        await fetch(url, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: formData,
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="min-h-screen bg-slate-900 text-white space-y-12">
            <div className="max-w-2xl mx-auto py-24 px-4">
                <h2 className="text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-white">
                    Admin Panel
                </h2>
                <p className="mt-1 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-400">
                    Upload the latest version of the pdf file.
                </p>

                <div className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6">
                    <div className="col-span-full">
                        <label
                            htmlFor="pdf-file"
                            className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-white"
                        >
                            PDF
                        </label>
                        <div className="mt-2 flex justify-center rounded-lg border border-dashed border-white/25 px-6 py-10">
                            <div className="text-center">
                                <DocumentIcon
                                    className="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-gray-500"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                />
                                <div className="mt-4 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-400">
                                    <label
                                        htmlFor="file-upload"
                                        className="relative cursor-pointer rounded-md bg-gray-900 font-semibold text-white focus-within:outline-none focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-indigo-600 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-offset-gray-900 hover:text-indigo-500"
                                    >
                                        <span>Upload a file</span>
                                        <input
                                            type="file"
                                            accept="application/pdf"
                                            id="file-upload"
                                            name="file-upload"
                                            className="sr-only"
                                            onChange={handleFileChange}
                                        />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <p className="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-400">
                                    {file?.name ? file.name : 'PDF up to 100MB'}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-6 flex items-center justify-end gap-x-6">
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="rounded-md bg-indigo-500 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-400 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-500"
                        onClick={handleUpload}
                    >
                        Upload
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Admin
```

#### app/api/upload/route.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import chalk from 'chalk'
import { PutObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner'

import { r2 } from '@/lib/r2'

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    try {
        console.log(chalk.yellow(`Generating an upload URL!`))

        const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(
            r2,
            new PutObjectCommand({
                Bucket: process.env.R2_BUCKET_NAME,
                Key: `filename.pdf`,
            }),
            { expiresIn: 60 }
        )

        console.log(chalk.green(`Success generating upload URL!`))

        return NextResponse.json({ url: signedUrl })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error')
    }
}
```

also, implemented download:

#### app/api/download/route.ts

```
import { GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
import chalk from 'chalk'

import { r2 } from '@/lib/r2'

export async function GET() {
    try {
        console.log(chalk.yellow(`Retrieving pdf from R2!`))

        const pdf = await r2.send(
            new GetObjectCommand({
                Bucket: process.env.R2_BUCKET_NAME,
                Key: 'filename.pdf',
            })
        )

        if (!pdf) {
            throw new Error('pdf not found.')
        }

        return new Response(pdf.Body?.transformToWebStream(), {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            },
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error', err)
    }
}
```

#### app/(site)/admin/page.tsx

```
const handleDownload = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/download')
    const blob = await response.blob()
    const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    let anchor = document.createElement('a')
    anchor.href = fileURL
    anchor.download = 'filename.pdf'
    anchor.click()
}

// add below upload button
<button
    type="button"
    className="rounded-md bg-pink-500 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-pink-400 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-pink-500"
    onClick={handleDownload}
>
    Download
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3 Compatible for R2 to achieve your goal.